# Error when installing connection broker server for RDS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i am currently hosting my ERP software on google cloud. The consultant has advise that we should use remote desktop as a point of access directly to the system. Currently, i want to increase the number of user for Remote desktop access. However when my technical consultant tries to install connection broker server for the RDS installation, he gets prompted by an error message. please refer to attachment for the print screen of the error.

[error print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQzN.jpg)

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is straightforward - enable PowerShell remoting.

[Tip: Enable and Use Remote Commands in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)